# Zsh prompt doesn't work on startup

Tags: command-prompt, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I have been playing around with zsh and on the initial startup of iterm2, I receive the following message:

[image]

The prompt then incorrectly outputs:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

This problem only happens on initial startup of iterm2, and displays the correctly formatted font when opening a new tab/window. How can I have the prompt start properly even on initial launch of iterm2?

Comment: Have you enabled to load iTerm preference from [custom location](https://i.imgur.com/osuVQkx.png) ?

Comment: I fixed this awhile back, but yes that exactly was the issue - I've since unchecked that box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customized Zsh prompt works after unchecking "Load preferences from a custom folder or URL" from iTerm Preferences > General > Preferences

[image: My iTerm Preferences]